# How to bind a Dropdownlist to new row in webgrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, webgrid

Is it possible to provide dropdownlist in the new row added to WebGrid? I tried adding this

```
'<td >@Html.DropDownList("Team", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Teams, "")</td>'
```

and it says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at `<td ><select id="Team" name="Team"><option value=""></option>`.

Code:

```
var row = '<tr class="webgrid-row-style">'+
          '<td class="col3Width"><input type="text" id="Date" value=""     class="edit-mode date-picker" /></td>' +
          '<td >@Html.DropDownList("Team", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Teams, "")</td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Name" value="" class="edit-mode /></span></td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Category" value="" class="edit-mode/></span></td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Received_Count" value="" class="edit-mode" /></span></td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Done_Count" value="" class="edit-mode" /></span></td>' +
          '<td ><button class="add-item edit-mode">Add</button>&nbsp;<button class="remove-item edit-mode">Cancel</button></td>' +
          '</tr>';

$('table tbody:last').append(row);
```

Error:

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or Unexpected token]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@Html.DropDownList` in a javascript string like

```
'<td >@Html.DropDownList("Team", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Teams, "")</td>'
```

it generates a string in multiple lines like below

```
'<td ><select id="Team" name="Team"><option value=""></option>
 <option>Sukantha</option>
 <option>Shruti</option>
 <option>Shilpa</option>
 <option>Sachin</option>
 <option>Ramya</option>
 <option>Nishmitha</option>
 <option>Mahesh</option>
 </select></td>'
```

which is invalid, hence you got the error.

As a workaround, try to place the `@Html.DropDownList` inside a hidden div somewhere in your view

```
<div id="divTeams" style="display: none;">
    @Html.DropDownList("Team", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Teams, "")
</div>
```

then get the generated string using `$('#divTeams').html()`

```
var row = '<tr class="webgrid-row-style">'+
          '<td class="col3Width"><input type="text" id="Date" value=""     class="edit-mode date-picker" /></td>' +
          '<td >' + $('#divTeams').html() + '</td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Name" value="" class="edit-mode /></span></td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Category" value="" class="edit-mode/></span></td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Received_Count" value="" class="edit-mode" /></span></td>' +
          '<td ><span><input type="text" id="Done_Count" value="" class="edit-mode" /></span></td>' +
          '<td ><button class="add-item edit-mode">Add</button>&nbsp;<button class="remove-item edit-mode">Cancel</button></td>' +
          '</tr>';

$('table tbody:last').append(row);
```

Comment: Hi, your answer works greatly, but in my code am assigning a dynamic IDs to these dropdown elements as below:
 'var e = document.getElementById("Team_");
                e.id = "Team_" + index;
                var f = document.getElementById("Name_");
                f.id = "Name_" + index;
                var g = document.getElementById("Category_");
                g.id = "Category_" + index;'
And when I try to get its selected value $("#Team_" + index).val(), it returns nothing. 
I inpected the code in chrome and IDs are perfectly assigned, but selected values are not returned.

Comment: Where do you assign the dynamic IDs exactly?

Comment: Here:
var existrow = $('.save').length;
            if (existrow == 0) {
var index = $("#grid tbody tr").length + 1;
var e = document.getElementById("Team_"); e.id = "Team_" + index;
e.id = "Team_" + index;
var f = document.getElementById("Name_"); f.id = "Name_" + index; var g = document.getElementById("Category_"); g.id = "Category_" + index;
var tr=............;
$("#grid tbody").append(tr);
}

Comment: Is your code executed when the `.save` button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, thats how I was able to put alerts inside .save function and see that the dropdownlists are returning nothing.
Also, values are returning from other input fields  (Date, Received_Count,Done_Count) without any issues.